# What would be the correct way to model user information in a nosql environment

Tags: java, nosql, spring-data, persistence

I have worked with relational dbs for the last 10 years and getting out of the relational model is quite a challenge. I started reading about the query first approach and I get it, now, the attempt to diagram that is what is quite different. 
This is what my question is about:
I have users and roles. So, a user can have various roles, or no roles. So, I store roles on a different db.
When modeling with nosql, there are no joins, so, one approach would be to have the user store the roles he manages in the form

UserTable:
{ id:..., name: 'Pedro Zuppelli', roles: [ {id:...,name: 'user'}, {id:..., name: 'admin'}]}

RoleTable:
{id:..., name:'user'}

but, what happens if a role name is updated in the roles table? that would not get modified in the users one.

Also, in the query first approach, if I would like to know which users has which roles I would create a UserByRole table. Now, when a user looses a role, I would not only have to update the user table, but the userByRole one. If a role changes name, the roles table, UserByRole and User table need to be updated.
Should that be done programatically in the service layer, or for instance Spring Data know how to handle it?

Any link to a book that covers this or code sample with complex data mappings would be greatly appretiated, I have been going through a bunch of tutos, videos and so on, and they all manage simple relations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

NoSQL suggest to embed roles and map objects to get list of roles.

```
{
  "type": "User",
  "roles": ["admin", "sudo", "wheel"]
}
```

When you need to change some role names - query all objects and update.

Another option is to use something with integrated query language like N1QL (JOINs, UPDATEs, DELETEs) and imitate relational database with it.

Comment: I saw that, I created a list that handles the roles by id, and then create 2 queries when doing a get.